# Insertion query C# sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have an insertion query in this function :

```
public string Insert_Piece(List<Piece> liste)
        {
            this.Connect();
            using (connexion)
            {

                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Piece (IDPiece, IDSuperlot, Url) VALUES (@idpiece, @idsuperlot, @url)", connexion))
                {
                    foreach (Piece p in liste)
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpiece", p.Id_piece);
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsuperlot", p.Id_super_lot);
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", p.Url_piece);
                        try
                        {
                            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) { return e.ToString(); }

                    }
                    return "cava";
                }
            }
        }
```

But always an exception appears:[image: error]

I don't know what is the problem and how can i fix it . The 3 attributs are string (varchar) and the selection queries works fine without problem.

- What is the matter?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: can you please translate the error in English, that will be very helpful.

Comment: I think it's "the string or binary data would be truncated"

Comment: So, one of your strings is too long for the column you are trying to insert it into (URL, probably)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue is you are trying to insert too long of a string into the varchar column, try making the varchar column larger or changing it to be a text column.

Comment: how can i change th type of the field url to text

Comment: Well @Lamloumi , open up whatever you used to initially create the database, I assume SQL Server Management Studio and on the dropdown just change varchar to text, or just change the number in the parentheses on the varchar to MAX and see if that fixes it.